# Como salvar o valor de uma variável no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, variáveis

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo pequeno só para amigos e fazer uns testes, o problema é que eu não sei praticamente nada de programação e fiquei preso na parte do salvamento de dados. Já li várias vezes e vi alguns exemplos mas não consegui fazer funcionar com meu código. Basicamente quero salvar o valor de "Derrotas por toque".

```
private Button botaoperder;
private TextView derrotas;
public int contador = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botaoperder= findViewById(R.id.botao1);
    derrotas= findViewById(R.id.derrotas00);

    botaoperder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            contador++;
            derrotas.setText("Derrotas por toques: " + contador);


        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

tente algo como:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
```

...

```
private Button botaoperder; 
private TextView derrotas;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public int contador = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("JogoToque", MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor = preferences.edit();

    botaoperder = findViewById(R.id.botao1);
    derrotas    = findViewById(R.id.derrotas00);

    contador = preferences.getInt("derrotas", 0);
    derrotas.setText("Derrotas por toques: " + contador);

    botaoperder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        contador++;
        derrotas.setText("Derrotas por toques: " + contador);
        editor.putInt("derrotas", contador);
        editor.commit();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Dando umas dicas a mais:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //Aqui é onde suas variaveis são "carregadas"
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("JogoToque", MODE_PRIVATE);
//Editor que permite você modificar os dados
    editor = preferences.edit();

    botaoperder = findViewById(R.id.botao1);
    derrotas    = findViewById(R.id.derrotas00);
//Aqui você atribui a sua variável contador o valor anteriormente salvo, através da key "derrotas"
    contador = preferences.getInt("derrotas", 0);
    derrotas.setText("Derrotas por toques: " + contador);

    botaoperder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        contador++;
        derrotas.setText("Derrotas por toques: " + contador);

      //Aqui você atribui a key "derrotas" o valor contido na int contador 
        editor.putInt("derrotas", contador);

      //Aqui você de fato "salva"
        editor.commit();
      }
    });
}
```